# Call function by using GetComponent with name without knowing it's actually type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have three types of balls(A, B, C) all inherit MotherBall, they all have thesame behavior only some setting is different.

There is an ObjectPool which I can get ball by balltype, then it will contain it's script(AScript, BScript or CScript)

The situation is I will randomly take ball from object pool, and I hope I can handle it in one function not separate.
Is there any way to call the Setting function like below code? I'm thinking maybe generic or delegates can slove it, or I need to write three functions.
Thanks, everyone.
P.S sorry my English is poor, I can't accurate describe my problem.

```C#
public void OneBallFire(string ballType){
    GameObject ball = ballPool.GetObjectFromPool (ballType);

    //I can't cast AScript, BScript or Motherball.
    MotherBall ballScript = ball.transform.GetComponent (ballType) as MotherBall;
    ballScript.Setting ();
}

public class MotherBall : MonoBehaviour{
    public virtual void Setting() {
      //Do nothing
    }
}

public class AScript : MotherBall {
    public  void Setting(){
      Debug.Log("Do A plan");
    }
}

public class BScript : MotherBall {
    public  void Setting(){
      Debug.Log("Do B plan");
    }
}

OneBallFire( RandomGetAorBorC() );
string RandomGetAorBorC(){
    //random return "AScript, BScript or CString" string.
}
```

Comment: Why do you cast the object to MotherBall if you want to use the Setting() function of ballType ?

Comment: That cast is wrong.  If `_ball` is **not** a `MotherBall` then you'll get a `NullReferenceException`.  If `_ball` is always a `MotherBall` then why cast it at all?

Comment: I know cast is wrong, but I can't cast to AScript or BScript, because the parameters of OneBallFire() is random(sometime is a,sometime is b) in my program. All Setting function of it do different thing.And I want only use one function to slove it.

Comment: You don't need delegates or generics, you just need to use inheritance correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work in your scenario but I would go with classic `is` `as` to get the actual script:

```
var component = ball.transform.GetComponent(customScript);
if (component is AScript)
{
    (component as AScript).Setting();
}
else if (component is BScript)
{
    (component as BScript).Setting();
}
else
{
    (component as MotherBall).Setting();
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

You need to update implementation of `BallPool` container in a way that you don't have to worry about sub-types and typecasting.

Here is a simple example:

I imagine you are storing ball gameObjects in a list. First thing I would do is use `List<MotherBall>` as container.

```
public class BallPool : Monobehaviour
{
    public List<MotherBall> ballPrefabs = new List<MotherBall>();
    ...
}
```

Add all kind of ball prefabs in this list from the inspector.

THen your method will look like this:

```
public MotherBall GetObjectFromPool()
{
    return Instantiate(ballPrefabs[Random.Range(0,ballPrefabs.Count));
}
```

Then in your other script:

```
public BallPool ballPool; // assign from the inspector

void Start() // or whatever other method
{
    var ball = ballPool.GetObjectFromPool();
    ball.Setting();
}
```

Now `ball.Setting()` will use the overridden method from either AScript or BScript depending on what object was selected and You don't need to worry about type as all the prefabs will have a script inherited from `MotherBall` so all must have `Setting()` if they don't have this method overridden then `MotherBall.Setting()` will be called.

---

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Although is solution seems a little Brute-force, but it can solve my problem, thanks a lot.

Comment: This isn't really a good solution, the code needs to know every type that inherits from `Motherball`.

Comment: Obviously code needs to know every type when you want to work with this kind of implementation of polymorphism which OP has. This is best of automation you can get when playing with strings instead of actual types. Hence easiest solution which solves OP's problem.

Comment: Or in my case, the best way is only use `MotherBall` and pass different setting in it to change it's behavior, and write all special function in it? By the way, I use `is` `as` in my program now.

Comment: I would suggest you consider polymorphism as this best suits in your case. Let me update my answer

Comment: This is what I exactly looking for, thank all of you to spend the time to answer my question.

Comment: No problem. @BanksySan you can retract your downvote now :)

Comment: @UmairM Not mine.

Comment: @BanksySan Apologies!

Answer (score 1):

No, because you're `overriding` the method.  If you need to have a method with the same signature as the base class's method you'll need to remove the `override` keyword and replace it with `new`.  Now you'll have two methods that are totally unrelated to each other, you access the one on the `Motherball` object by casting to `Motherball`.

```csharp
public class AScript : MotherBall {
    public new void Setting(){
      //Do something
    }
}

var _ball = new AScript();
_ball.Setting() // calls Setting on AScript
((MotherBall) _ball).Setting(); // Calls Setting on MotherBall
```

What I suspect you want to do though is invoke the base method when you call `Setting()` on the `AScript` class.  You have two options here.

1. Just remove the method in `AScript` completely, any call to `AScript.Setting()` will invoke the base class's `Setting()` method.
2. Call the base class's `Setting()` method from the `AScript` classes method, to do this use the `base` keyword, e.g. `base.Setting()`.

Comment: My previous question's title is wrong because my poor English, I don't really want to call the parent's function. Which I want is to cast ball dynamic. No matter what this answer also help me a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generic type is better solution for your case , And more Simply

```
public void OneBallFire<T>() where T : MotherBall
{
    GameObject ball = ballPool.GetObjectFromPool<T>(ballType);

    //I can't cast AScript, BScript or Motherball.
    T ballScript = ball.transform.GetComponent<T>();
    ballScript.Setting();
}

// BoolPool Todo This
public T GetObjectFromPool<T>()
{
    if(T is AScript)
       //Clone && Return a AScript Obj
    // Todo all type ....

    return null;
}
```